# Change delimiters in petite-vue

Tags: vue.js, petite-vue

I want something like this:

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
```

But in petite vue.

PetiteVue object doesn't have config. I want this setting to be global.

If it is possible this also can be in

```
v-scope="{{here}}".
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, in v0.3+ is added I was using 0.2.2.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/petite-vue"></script>
<script>
    PetiteVue.createApp({ $delimiters: ['${', '}'] }).mount()
</script>
```